# MDX Column Alias for use in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I'm trying to query our SSAS cubes and return the values into a SQL view for use as parameters in cube based reports.

I need to return 3 values for financial seasons based on the date hierarchy.

This is the below code, which returns the correct data.

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [CurrentHalf] AS [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME
    MEMBER [NextHalf] AS [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].LEAD(1).UNIQUENAME
    MEMBER [PreviousHalf] AS [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].LEAD(-1).UNIQUENAME

SELECT {[Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].[Season Half]} ON COLUMNS , 
        {[CurrentHalf],NextHalf,PreviousHalf} ON ROWS
FROM [Sales and Stock]

WHERE  (Filter([Date - Master].[DateKey].Members,[Date - Master].[DateKey].MemberValue = (format(now(),"dd/MM/yyyy"))))
```

However the column name for [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].[Season Half] returns the caption value (e.g. 2014- Autumn /Winter).

See image:

[image]

Normally this would be fine however as I am passing it into SQL I need a column name to select off. What I need is to rename this column to something else (e.g. HalfName)

I have tried

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [CurrentHalf] AS [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME
    MEMBER [NextHalf] AS [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].LEAD(1).UNIQUENAME
    MEMBER [PreviousHalf] AS [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].LEAD(-1).UNIQUENAME
    MEMBER [HalfName] as [Date - Master].[Financial Calendar].[Season Half].CURRENTMEMBER.VALUE

SELECT {[HalfName]} ON COLUMNS , 
        {[CurrentHalf],NextHalf,PreviousHalf} ON ROWS
FROM [Sales and Stock]

WHERE  (Filter([Date - Master].[DateKey].Members,[Date - Master].[DateKey].MemberValue = (format(now(),"dd/MM/yyyy"))))
```

But that still didn't work.

Comment: I think you are expecting a table when your MDX query is returning a matrix. What happens if you change your original query to select nothing (empty braces) on columns? Does that give you what you want?

Comment: What is the result you want to see? And how to you interface with SQL? Via a linked server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define `MEMBER` expressions as you have, it infers you are creating them on the `[Measures]` dimension, so the full name of your `[HalfName]` column is `[Measures].[HalfName]`.

Also, I don't see where SQL/T-SQL come into this, unless you are mistaking your MDX for SQL (they look similar as they share some syntax, but are very different beasts).

Comment: Thanks, The SQL comes into it as I need to select the column with an open query so I need the column name. I get the following when I try to select {[Measures].[HalfName]

 Executing the query ...
The Measures hierarchy already appears in the Axis0 axis.

Comment: @WillWainwright yes, you can't use the same hierarchy on multiple axis, but a workaround is to change the `ON ROWS` members to `MEMBER [Date - Master].[CurrentHalf] ...etc` then use that full name on rows, effectively making them dynamic members of your `[Date - Master]` dimension.